# Extract row wise common substring within more than 2 columns dataframe R

Tags: r, dplyr

In a microbiology lineage classifier I want to compare three methods. I have the family, genus and specie taxonomic ranks, separated each one by ";" in a R dataframe (df).

As a toy example, I have the next df:

```
df <- data.frame(classifier_a = c("Lachnospiraceae;Blautia;NA", 'Succinivibrionaceae;Succinivibrio;NA', 'NA;NA;NA'), 
                 classifier_b = c('Lachnospiraceae;Blautia;Blautia faecis', 'Succinivibrionaceae;Succinivibrio;NA', 'UGC-10;NA;NA'), 
                 classifier_c= c('Lachnospiraceae;Blautia;Blautia faecis', 'Succinivibrionaceae;Succinivibrio;Succinivibrio dextrinosolvens', 'NA;NA;NA'))

df
```

For each row I am interested to find out the method or methods that gives me the same results (for this I thought with the statistical mode concept). Nevertheless, If I apply this approach, does not work as I desire because I obtain the following output:

```
df$Row_mode <- apply(df[,1:3],1, function(x) {names(which.max(table(factor(x,unique(x)))))})

df <- data.frame(classifier_a = c("Lachnospiraceae;Blautia;NA", 'Succinivibrionaceae;Succinivibrio;NA', 'NA;NA;NA'), 
                 classifier_b = c('Lachnospiraceae;Blautia;Blautia faecis', 'Succinivibrionaceae;Succinivibrio;NA', 'UGC-10;NA;NA'), 
                 classifier_c= c('Lachnospiraceae;Blautia;Blautia faecis', 'Succinivibrionaceae;Succinivibrio;Succinivibrio dextrinosolvens', 'NA;NA;NA'),
                 Row_mode=c("Lachnospiraceae;Blautia;Blautia faecis", "Succinivibrionaceae;Succinivibrio;NA","NA;NA;NA"))
```

In the new Row_mode variable created in the first row I obtained the desired output: Lachnospiraceae;Blautia;Blautia faecis. Nevertheless, on the second row I do not obtain the classification obtained by classifier_c which is the only that gives me the family, genus and specie. It is normal because I used the mode concept.

Therefore, I need a part from the mode to take into account the maximization of the three taxonomic levels. In this second case I would like to obtain the case:

```
Succinivibrionaceae;Succinivibrio;Succinivibrio dextrinosolvens instead of Succinivibrionaceae;Succinivibrio;NA
```

And finnally in the third row, I would like to obtain the case which less NA values although it is not the statistical mode.

In general terms, I like the mode statistical because from 3 classifier methods I hope to obtain similar taxonomic lineage but in each row I desire to obtain the longest (more informative) lineage from almost one of the three methods compared.

On summary, the desired output is:

```
df <- data.frame(classifier_a = c("Lachnospiraceae;Blautia;NA", 'Succinivibrionaceae;Succinivibrio;NA', 'NA;NA;NA'), 
                 classifier_b = c('Lachnospiraceae;Blautia;Blautia faecis', 'Succinivibrionaceae;Succinivibrio;NA', 'UGC-10;NA;NA'), 
                 classifier_c= c('Lachnospiraceae;Blautia;Blautia faecis', 'Succinivibrionaceae;Succinivibrio;Succinivibrio dextrinosolvens', 'NA;NA;NA'),
                 desired_output=c("Lachnospiraceae;Blautia;Blautia faecis", "Succinivibrionaceae;Succinivibrio;Succinivibrio dextrinosolvens","UGC-10;NA;NA"))
```

Thanks on advance for your help and hints.

Comment: Please show the expected output

Comment: Thanks @akrun. Included now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer (to account for multiple minimum, dataset in the comment):

```
least_na <- function(x){
  index <- stringr::str_count(x,"NA")
  paste(x[which(index==min(index))],collapse="|")
}
df_2$Row_mode <- apply(df_2,1,least_na)

> df_2$Row_mode
[1] "Lachnospiraceae;Blautia;Blautia faecis|Lachnospiraceae;Escherichia;Escherichia coli"
```

We can create user-defined function for this:

```
least_na <- function(x){
  x[which.min(str_count(x,"NA"))]
}

df$Row_mode <- apply(df,1,least_na)

> df$Row_mode
[1] "Lachnospiraceae;Blautia;Blautia faecis"                         
[2] "Succinivibrionaceae;Succinivibrio;Succinivibrio dextrinosolvens"
[3] "UGC-10;NA;NA"
```

Comment: Thanks @peter861222 for the user-defined function. Nevertheless, I need to add an extra argument in this function because I forgot that in some cases more than one method could have info without NA and I desire to obtain the info. Let me explain, let's suppose we have the following case: `df_2 <- data.frame(classifier_a = c("Lachnospiraceae;Blautia;NA"), 
                 classifier_b = c('Lachnospiraceae;Blautia;Blautia faecis'), 
                 classifier_c= c('Lachnospiraceae;Escherichia;Escherichia coli'))
` I would like to obtain the output from classifier_b and _c. Thanks on advance

Comment: Then the desired output would be (using for example | as separator between both methods): `data.frame(classifier_a = c("Lachnospiraceae;Blautia;NA"),                   classifier_b = c('Lachnospiraceae;Blautia;Blautia faecis'),                   classifier_c= c('Lachnospiraceae;Escherichia;Escherichia coli'), desired_output=c('Lachnospiraceae;Blautia;Blautia faecis' | 'Lachnospiraceae;Escherichia;Escherichia coli')` How can achieve this? Thanks again

Comment: No problem. The answer is updated.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you used which.max to find the **most common** answer between the three classifiers, which is why you get Succinivibrionaceae;Succinivibrio;NA  instead of Succinivibrionaceae;Succinivibrio;Succinivibrio dextrinosolvens in column 2.

I changed your code to use which.max to find the **longest** answer between the three classifiers. This will correspond to that that gives you the family, genus and species in your toy example.

```
df <- data.frame(classifier_a = c("Lachnospiraceae;Blautia;NA", 'Succinivibrionaceae;Succinivibrio;NA', 'NA;NA;NA'), 
                 classifier_b = c('Lachnospiraceae;Blautia;Blautia faecis', 'Succinivibrionaceae;Succinivibrio;NA', 'UGC-10;NA;NA'), 
                 classifier_c= c('Lachnospiraceae;Blautia;Blautia faecis', 'Succinivibrionaceae;Succinivibrio;Succinivibrio dextrinosolvens', 'NA;NA;NA'))


df$Row_mode <- apply(df, 1, function(x) {x[which.max(nchar(x))]})
df
```

Which returns:

```
classifier_a                           classifier_b                                                    classifier_c
1           Lachnospiraceae;Blautia;NA Lachnospiraceae;Blautia;Blautia faecis                          Lachnospiraceae;Blautia;Blautia faecis
2 Succinivibrionaceae;Succinivibrio;NA   Succinivibrionaceae;Succinivibrio;NA Succinivibrionaceae;Succinivibrio;Succinivibrio dextrinosolvens
3                             NA;NA;NA                           UGC-10;NA;NA                                                        NA;NA;NA
                                                         Row_mode
1                          Lachnospiraceae;Blautia;Blautia faecis
2 Succinivibrionaceae;Succinivibrio;Succinivibrio dextrinosolvens
3                                                    UGC-10;NA;NA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>%
  rowid_to_column()%>%
  separate_rows(everything(), sep = ';') %>%
  mutate(new_col = do.call('coalesce', across(-1, ~na_if(.,'NA'))),
         new_col = replace_na(new_col, 'NA'))%>%
  group_by(rowid) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~str_c(.x, collapse = ';')))
```